# Is there any way to log "kubectl describe" of all objects loaded by "helm install"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using **helm** to deploy my applications which has deployments, pods and jobs and others.
Is there any way to get "**kubectl describe**" output of all objects loaded by "**helm install**" ?

Comment: yes objects installed via helm has a common label you can use that to describe all objects with that label. `kubectl describe po -l chart=chart-name`

Comment: there is no common label, but the namespace is common to all.

Comment: It would be easier if you share which chart you installed for example

Comment: helm install  myb5 --namespace myb5 cn-helm-chart -f cn-helm-chart/override-values.yaml

Comment: "kubectl get all -l chart=myb5 -n myb5" doesn't give you the associated resources?

Comment: Also applications deployed by helm have this label also `app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: helm` . Since this chart is made be you in local you can add the labels yourself also.

Comment: Helm 3 provide "get" subcommand, particulary might help `helm get manifest <release-name>`

Comment: The François suggestion is good, it works for you? @François, you can post as an answer and elaborate a bit more, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if it is working, but I tried with my helm charts (custom one, ES and kibana).

### TL;DR

```
kubectl get all -l chart=myb5 -n myb5
```

`-n` stands for namespace
`-l` stands for label

### Explanations

Labeling your kubernetes objects is really important, and most of the helm charts out there are using labels to easily access and select objects.

When you install a chart, it adds a label such `chart=my-chart-name`. If the chart is not using it (maybe you are creating one for yourself), it is a good practice to add it.

So querying all resources with `get all` should retrieve all the resources created in the **default** namespace.

Depending where you installed your helm chart, it is good to add the namespace field in your query.

**Note** that if you use 1 namespace for only 1 helm chart resources, you do not need to filter with labels.

PS: should work the same with describe ;)

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `helm install`, i assume your Chart's resources are installed into a specific namespace.

In that case, you can simply use the command `kubectl describe all -n <your-namespace>`.
Its output should be the same as using `kubectl describe` on each resource of your Helm Chart.

Comment: I dont agree with you. In a namespace, you can install as many helm charts as you want. So, you statement is incorrect to get the resources associated with one chart only. How does the resources in the namespace mean that they are the same as in a helm chart release?

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl describe all -l chart=<chartName> -n namespace`

or

`kubectl get events -n namespace -w`